# 'ogr2ogr' is not recognized as internal or external command

Tags: python, json, geojson

I am working my way through [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/) but when I get to this step:

```
  ogr2ogr \
  -f GeoJSON \
  -where "ADM0_A3 IN ('GBR', 'IRL')" \
  subunits.json \
  ne_10m_admin_0_map_subunits.shp
```

I get the error message : 'ogr2ogr' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch command

I found [this on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567450/error-ogr2ogr-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable) but I'm not sure how to "reinstall the Python bindings" -- can anyone explain?

Comment: How did you install GDAL?

Comment: I went to this page: http://www.gisinternals.com/query.html?content=filelist&file=release-1500-x64-gdal-1-11-1-mapserver-6-4-1.zip and installed the file named gdal-111-1500-x64-core. Thanks for responding

Answer (score 0):

Oops!  I was running all these commands in the node.js command prompt, but it seems I should have been running them in the regular cmd.exe. I am not really sure what the difference is, but it worked fine running through cmd.exe